# Is it safe to delete temp files under inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories

Tags: 2013, iis

Hi is it safe to delete temp files under below path for a SharePoint production web application?
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\VirtualdirectoryName\temp

Comment: what type of files you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked several farms and none of them had a `temp` folder in it's VirtualDirectory.

So the answer is NO. You should not delete those files if you don't know the application creating them.